# Error while configuring active directory LDS using ADSI edit

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am new to Active Directory. I want to create few users in active directory. From some research I found out I can do with the help of ADSI edit console.

- I enabled Active Directory LDS on my Windows 8.1 machine using 'Turn Windows feature on OR off'.
- Then I followed 'Use the ADSI Edit administration tool' section from link
  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732675(v=ws.10).aspx

[image]

- But I am getting error

[image]

What AM I doing wrong?

What is the correct way of creating users in Active Directory?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the correct way. I was missing the initial steps of Setup and Configuration of AD-LDS which I found on
https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2015/07/01/in-windows-10-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-adlds-can-be-found-under-programs-and-features/